# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 synapse ciphertool

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

is there a way to create a new jks only for synapse secure vault(ciphsertool)?

I configured ciphertool like in this manual https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+Passwords+in+the+ESB+profile  or this https://www.chakray.com/wso2-esb-tutorial-how-to-programmatically-manage-secure-vault-passwords/

I didn't find how to set up another keystore for encryption only

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes when encrypting/decrypting passwords the server will be using the following keystore configuration block in carbon.xml

```xml
<InternalKeyStore>
 <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/internal.jks</Location>
  <Type>JKS</Type>
  <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
  <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
  <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
</InternalKeyStore>
```

So you can create a new keystore and change the configuration here and then change the cipher tool's keystore configurations at secret-conf.properties to point to the newly created keystore. You can read more [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products).